# creating UI components based on array values swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of string and for each string value, I want to create a UILabel to display the text that means if I have 10 stings in the array, i want to have 10 labels with the string name. I am doing this programmaticalyy but since, it does not work and nothing is shown. This is what I have tried

```
let const: [String] = ["Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer"]

var checkBox: BEMCheckBox!
var checkLabel: DefaultLabel!
var checkboxStack: DefaultStackView?

fileprivate func setupButton() {
        const.forEach { (title) in
            checkBox = BEMCheckBox()
            checkBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            checkBox.tintColor = UIColor.ZAMA.offWhite
            checkBox.onCheckColor = UIColor.ZAMA.primary
            checkBox.onFillColor = UIColor.ZAMA.tabColor
            checkBox.onTintColor = UIColor.ZAMA.primary
            checkBox.onAnimationType = .flat
            checkBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
            checkBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

            checkLabel = UILabel()
            checkLabel.text = title
            checkLabel.textColor = .black
            checkLabel.fontSize = 15

            checkboxStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [centralCoolingCheckbox, centralCoolingText])
            checkboxStack?.axis = .horizontal
            checkboxStack?.spacing =  4
            checkboxStack?.alignment = .fill
            checkboxStack?.distribution = .fill
        }
    }

fileprivate func layout() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        setupButton()
        stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [checkboxStack ?? DefaultStackView()])
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.spacing = 8

        view.addSubview(stack)

        stack.anchor(top: contentView.topAnchor, left: contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: contentView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 8, width: 0, height: 0, enableInsets: false)
    }
```

layout() is then called in viewDidLoad

Comment: your code won't compile for re-produce as of custom views check below how it's be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like

**Without ScrollView**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let const  = ["Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let st = UIStackView()
        st.axis = .vertical
        st.alignment = .center
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        view.addSubview(st)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            st.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            st.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            st.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
        ])

        const.forEach {
            let lbl = UILabel()
            lbl.text = $0
            st.addArrangedSubview(lbl)
        } 
    } 
}
```

[image]

**With ScrollView**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let const = ["Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer","Central Cooling Unit", "Split Cooling Unit", "Oven", "Refridgerator", "Dish Washer"]

    let scroll = UIScrollView()
    let st = UIStackView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        st.axis = .vertical
        st.alignment = .center
        scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        st.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        view.addSubview(scroll)
        scroll.addSubview(st)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scroll.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            scroll.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            scroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),

            st.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor),
            st.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scroll.leadingAnchor),
            st.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scroll.trailingAnchor),
            st.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scroll.topAnchor),
            st.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.scroll.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        const.forEach {
            let lbl = UILabel()
            lbl.text = $0
            st.addArrangedSubview(lbl)
        }
    } 
}
```